# Appending to a list fails. Printed just one of the pieces. How can the loop be fixed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

The following Code gives result only for the first Piece of DNA, the "append" somehow does not append and the list is not Extended.

```
DNA= open("Ex72_genomic_dna2.txt", "r")
EXON = open("Ex72_exons2.txt", "r")
DNAST = []
DNAseq = DNA.read()

for li in EXON:
    positions = li.split(',')
    start = int (positions[0]) -1
    stop = int (positions[1])
    # start = 1, stop = 8
    piece = str (DNAseq [start:stop])
    # piece = 'CGATCGT'
    DNAST.append(piece)
    print (DNAST)

NewDNA = DNAST [0]
rangemax = len(DNAST)


if rangemax > 1:
    for num in range (1, rangemax):
        NewDNA = NewDNA + "" + DNAST [num]
DNA.close()
EXON.close()
print (NewDNA)
print ("But should be CGATCGTCCGTCCGATGCCGATCG")
# the Content of Ex72_genomic_dna2.txt: TCGATCGTACCGTCGACGATGCTACGATCGTCGAT
#the Content of  Ex72_exons2.txt:    2,8,10,14,17,22,25,30
```

Comment: I added two comments to you code. The for li in EXON loop is only executed once and you add the piece = "CGATCGT" to DNAST. What is it you are trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises I think because you thought `for li in EXON:` would iterate each item in the `Ex72_exons2.txt` file. The correct way to do this is to iterate over each line as before but then iterate over each split in that line.

This is correct code that works for your situation:

```
DNA= open("Ex72_genomic_dna2.txt", "r")
EXON = open("Ex72_exons2.txt", "r")
DNAST = []
DNAseq = DNA.read()

for li in EXON:
    positions = li.split(',')
    for i in range(0, len(positions), 2):
        start = int (positions[i]) -1
        # .strip() because of trailing newline character.
        stop = int (positions[i+1].strip())
        piece = str (DNAseq [start:stop])
        DNAST.append(piece)
        print (DNAST)

NewDNA = DNAST [0]
rangemax = len(DNAST)

if rangemax > 1:
    for num in range (1, rangemax):
        NewDNA = NewDNA + "" + DNAST [num]

DNA.close()
EXON.close()
print (NewDNA)
print ("CGATCGTCCGTCCGATGCCGATCG") # <-- correct output for comparison.
```

It's also worth pointing out that this part of the code:

```
NewDNA = DNAST [0]
rangemax = len(DNAST)

if rangemax > 1:
    for num in range (1, rangemax):
        NewDNA = NewDNA + "" + DNAST [num]
```

can be replaced with:

```
NewDNA = ''.join(DNAST)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the value for **li** in `for li in EXON:` would be the entire content of EXON. i.e if Ex72_exons2.txt had the text '1,2,3,4', li will be '1,2,3,4' and the loop will iterate only once. The solution from torrentails will fix the issue you are having.